How to set indentation for JTextArea?
I am trying to make my own IDE with Java. In the project, there is a JTextArea to write code but i want to handle indentation correctly.
private void handleEnterKey() {
        Document doc = getDocument();
        int caretPosition = getCaretPosition();
    
        if (isBetweenPairs(caretPosition)) {
            try {
                doc.insertString(caretPosition, "\n", null);
    
                int indentLevel = 1;
    
                StringBuilder indentation = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < TAB_SIZE * indentLevel; i++) {
                    indentation.append(' ');
                }
                doc.insertString(caretPosition + 1, indentation.toString(), null);
                setCaretPosition(getCaretPosition()-1);
            } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

Here, if i delete this line:
setCaretPosition(getCaretPosition()-1);

the text area seems like this:
currentline{

|}

so i say go 1 step back but this doesn't work as expected and seems like this:
currentline{

 |}


I cannot reproduce that exact problem (removing the setCaretPosition call works for me... but I do not know how handleEnterKey is being called, what else ENTER is triggering. Maybe better creeate and include a [mre] in this question

( BTW String has a repeat() method {e.g. for indentation} )

I solved the problem. HandleEnterKey() method works before the actual 'Enter' key which is for moving next line. So if i say setCaretPosition(getCaretPosition()-1), it moves back first and then enter does it's own work.
I use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> handleEnterKey()); and problem is gone.
